# Why i am not able to open file picker in android 10 and showing toast Failed to create image file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-design-library, android-fileprovider

I am not able to open file picker in android 10 and showing toast  Failed to create image file...but working fine in android 9.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: we're going to need some code to be able to help you.

Comment: @androidkumar , I am also facing same issue .Can u please answer if it is solved .

Comment: You must use app directory to store the File. Remove the Relative access Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Google have made file paths outside of the App's private directories useless with their scoped storage changes in Android 10, as the picture is of a non standard file picker, I guess it has not been updated (or deprecated as you can do a lot with the builtin stuff)

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Depending on the types of files you need to use MediaStore or Storage Access Framework (SAF), details https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared for files outside of your App's private directories.

As it looks like picking photos, you might be able to use Google photo app to pick.

Though as a quick fix is to temporarily opt out https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/compatibility but this will only work until Android 11